Can I use egg whites instead of whole eggs in meatballs?
I made egg custard and I have leftover egg whites. Will it work to use just egg whites as the binder in meatballs? I have not tried this yet.

While egg whites have a lower protein content than yolk, they should be fine as a binder in a meatball situation.  Seems like a good use for extra egg whites.

Slightly less than half the protein in an egg is from the white (albumen) and slightly more than half from yolk, but white contains only about 11 g/100 ml while yolk contains about 17 g/100 ml, so gram for gram there's more protein in yolk. The half-half is mostly because white makes up most of the volume in an egg.

Maringue is the only proper use for leftover egg whites.

@GdD In that case you need to try Pavlova. It's not as dry and hard as meringue, and (when done properly) has a marshmallow-like texture inside.
